# To write a a block of data in a file from edit text in click of a button

Tags: android, android-intent

Hii I am New to Android Development an i am trying this simple application and my issues is
I am Trying to save a block of data from Edit Text to a file on click of a Button
but I am unable to do so!
my Block of Code is

```
 saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String str = textBox.getText().toString();

        try
        {

            FileOutputStream fOut =
            openFileOutput("textfile.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);


            osw.write();
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "file path" + getFileStreamPath ("textfile.txt"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            textBox.setText("");
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Where is your textBox.getText().toString()? And your button's onClick() method? What's problem?

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg20408.html check out link it will help u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were unable to do so because you not passing the Str value 
ie String str = textBox.getText().toString();

to:-  osw.write();
Like I have Done

osw.write(str);

this will solve your problem I have Tested this

for more such resources, just have a look at the below site

http://www.suvenconsultants.com/